# [python]Filter on opposites values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I would like to create a filter that allows me to retrieve only the values ​​of opposite signs on a certain column. (example 10, -10, 22, -22)

How can I do this? Thanks

[image: Example]

I would like to keep only B codes whose opposite value is in A, typically:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic and expected output is unclear (please provide an example), bus you could use the absolute value and the sign as groupers:

```
out = (df
 .assign(abs=df['col'].abs(), sign=np.sign(df['col']))
 .pivot(index='abs', columns='sign')
)
```

output:

```
       id        col      
sign   -1    1    -1     1
abs                       
4     NaN  4.0   NaN   4.0
7     5.0  NaN  -7.0   NaN
10    3.0  0.0 -10.0  10.0
22    2.0  1.0 -22.0  22.0
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(6),
                   'col': [10, 22, -22, -10, 4, -7],
                  })

   id  col
0   0   10
1   1   22
2   2  -22
3   3  -10
4   4    4
5   5   -7
```

Comment: @Lidse please move your example to the question (use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72785413/edit) link) and provide **text** (ideally DataFrame constructors), not images